# feed pre-computed estimates to TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I trained an instance of scikit-learn's `TfidfVectorizer` and I want to persist it to disk. I saved the IDF matrix (the `idf_` attribute) to disk as a numpy array and I saved the vocabulary (`vocabulary_`) to disk as a JSON object (I'm avoiding pickle, for security and other [reasons](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations)). I'm trying to do this:

```
import json
from idf import idf # numpy array with the pre-computed IDFs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# dirty trick so I can plug my pre-computed IDFs
# necessary because "vectorizer.idf_ = idf" doesn't work,
# it returns "AttributeError: can't set attribute."
class MyVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer):
    TfidfVectorizer.idf_ = idf

# instantiate vectorizer
vectorizer = MyVectorizer(lowercase = False,
                          min_df = 2,
                          norm = 'l2',
                          smooth_idf = True)

# plug vocabulary
vocabulary = json.load(open('vocabulary.json', mode = 'rb'))
vectorizer.vocabulary_ = vocabulary

# test it
vectorizer.transform(['foo bar'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1314, in transform
    return self._tfidf.transform(X, copy=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1014, in transform
    check_is_fitted(self, '_idf_diag', 'idf vector is not fitted')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 627, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.utils.validation.NotFittedError: idf vector is not fitted
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I'm failing to fool the vectorizer object: somehow it knows that I'm cheating (i.e., passing it pre-computed data and not training it with actual text). I inspected the attributes of the vectorizer object but I can't find anything like 'istrained', 'isfitted', etc. So, how do I fool the vectorizer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it: the vectorizer instance has an attribute `_tfidf`, which in turn must have an attribute `_idf_diag`. The `transform` method calls a `check_is_fitted` function that checks whether whether that `_idf_diag` exists. (I had missed it because it's an attribute of an attribute.) So, I inspected the TfidfVectorizer [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py) to see how `_idf_diag` is created. Then I just added it to the `_tfidf` attribute:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

# ... code ...

vectorizer._tfidf._idf_diag = sp.spdiags(idf,
                                         diags = 0,
                                         m = len(idf),
                                         n = len(idf))
```

And now the vectorization works.